# How can I set a footnote at the bottom of the page using the same footnote twice?

Tags: pdftex, texworks

I'm using the following commands in my file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, openright, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[paper = A4, pagesize]{typearea}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue, citecolor = cyan, filecolor = green]{hyperref}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,top=3cm,headheight=40pt,footskip=40pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{cleveref}[2012/02/15]   
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]   
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}   
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{30pt}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesection}{10pt}{}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead[LE, RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE]{\textsl{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textsl{\leftmark}}

\setlength{\headheight}{16mm}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\crefformat{footnote}{#2\footnotemark[#1]#3}

\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}         
\setlength{\parindent}{8mm}

\begin{document}

This is the first footnote\footnote{\label{note1}First note}.

This is, also, the first footnote \cref{note1}.

\end{document}
```

but can't get the superscript 1 in the use of \cref, but I don't know why.

Thanks you very much in advance!

Comment: If you say "This is, also, the first footnote 1" and "1" is there a superscript... it will be show as a new footnote with the same label ("1"). So, I suggest to use just `\ref{note1}` that will be better without superscript. If you insist to make it a superscript for any other case : `\textsuperscript{\ref{note1}}` should work...

Comment: Welcome. Also, if you wish the referenced label to lead at your footnote's text try `\footnote{\phantomsection\label{note1}}` instead. (click at the place you use the `\ref` command in a text with a next page too in order to see where the reference leads to.)